# unexpected %%X in OSGeo4W

Tags: osgeo4w

This code worked fine before but now I'm getting this error:

```
%%X was unexpected at this time
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
cd /d C:\Users\user\Documents\PhiladelphiaBaseLayers
set ogr2ogrPath="c:\program files\QGIS Essen\bin\ogr2ogr.exe"
set GDAL_DATA=C:\program files\QGIS Essen\share\gdal
for %%X in (*.shp) do %ogr2ogrPath% -skipfailures -clipsrc C:\Users\user\Documents\PhiladelphiaBaseLayers\clipFeature\city_limits.shp C:\Users\user\Documents\PhiladelphiaBaseLayers\clipped\%%X C:\Users\user\Documents\PhiladelphiaBaseLayers\%%X
for %%X in (*.shp) do %ogr2ogrPath% -skipfailures -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857  C:\Users\user\Documents\PhiladelphiaBaseLayers\clippedAndProjected\%%X C:\Users\user\Documents\PhiladelphiaBaseLayers\clipped\%%X
```

Went back and forth through the original code but I can't find where I'm off.

I made this code to test the directory for any folders that have "shp" in the name:

```
import os 

files = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\user\Documents\PhiladelphiaBaseLayers")

shpNames = []

for f in files:
    if f[-3:] == "shp":
        shpNames.append(f)
for f in shpNames:
    print f
```

All files within seem to be legitimate shapefiles

```
arts_centres.shp
atms.shp
banks.shp
bars.shp
bicycle_parking.shp
bus_stops.shp
cafes.shp
cemetery.shp
fast_food.shp
fire_stations.shp
fuel.shp
hospitals.shp
hotels.shp
landuse.shp
libraries.shp
movies.shp
museums.shp
natural.shp
places.shp
places_of_worship.shp
police_stations.shp
railways.shp
restaurants.shp
roads.shp
schools.shp
stations.shp
swimming_pools.shp
toilets.shp
waterways.shp
```

Comment: Can you check if all .shp are really files, and not a folder named .shp in between too?

Comment: checked. No folders with .shp. See modified post.

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/for.html : "If you are using the FOR command at the command line rather than in a batch program, use just one percent sign: %G instead of %%G." Maybe this is the error?

Comment: @Redoute Ok, I'll give it a shot

Comment: @Redoute Now I am getting a message that the system cannot find the specified path. I've checked a dozen times. Copy and pasted ogrsogr.exe as well GDAL. Also and copy and pasted Philadelphia base layers into the directory into the script.

Comment: Are `clipped` and `clippedAndProjected` existing folders? I think you have to create them explicit.

Comment: Yes. They do exist and I've copied and pasted their paths into the script directly.